# How to access web service on port other than 80 in vs2008/2010

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, asmx, wsdl.exe

I tried searching the net, also tried some workarounds I found (like manually executing wsdl.exe) but still I can't access a remote web service running on a port different than 80 (say 1234).

When from Visual Studio 2008 OR 2010 I add a web reference using a url like `http://192.168.1.2:1234/WebServices/Test.asmx`, the service is found but when I press Continue, VS is unable to create the proxy classes and gives me an error saying that *`http://192.168.1.2/WebServices/Test.asmx`* (notice the missing port) was unable to return anything. Is there something I can do apart from creating the web service localy, creating the proxy classes and then manually changing the url?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're *supposed to* set the `Url` property on the web service proxy class.